# Стирка или стёрка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно "ст**и**рка" или "ст**ё**рка", когда говорят о стирательной резинке?  
И ещё попутный вопрос: откуда взялось слово "ластик", обозначающее всё тот же предмет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба слова, стирка и стёрка, как обозначение стирательной резинки разговорные, говорить о бОльшей правильности одного по отношению к другому в таких случаях не имеет смысла. 
"Стирать" и "стереть" — глаголы, образующие видовую пару, в каком-то смысле — формы одного слова. Поэтому точно так же не имеют смысла разговоры о том, от какого из них могло или не могло произойти стирка/стёрка.
Более продуктивным, пожалуй, является образование от глагола несовершенного вида (сравните: решалка — от решать, не решить).
Хотя "стёрка", наверное, более понятно поскольку "стирка" имеет и другое значение.

Ластик — от "эластик", "эластичный".

Comment: У нас в детстве (Сахалин) была стерка. Ластиков "не было", слово "ластик" впервые прочитала.

Comment: Какие края-то... Согласен, стрерка - наиболее употребительное. Но "ластик" тоже было довольно популярно в столицах. Да, думаю и не только в них.

Comment: Ластик - это уж "гламур". Мы говорили "стиралка" или "стёрка". Так что обе гласные использованы...

Comment: Точно! Еще стиралка была!

Comment: FCTL, спасибо за правку. Мне было трудно себя проверять на ранних стадиях существования проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что правильным вариантом будет "стирка", так как слово произошло от глагола "стирать", в котором есть суффикс "а", ввиду которого корень "стир", а не "стер". 
Конечно, те, кто говорит "стёрка", могут заявить, что в самом этом слове нет суффикса "а", поэтому пишем "стер", но тогда они не смогут найти родителя этого слова (не "стёрать" же).
Большой словарь русских поговорок говорит: "Большая стёрка. Жарг. шк. Стиральная резинка. ВМН 2003, 128. /em> По названию популярной телепередачи «Большая стирка»." Про "стирку" он говорит это же.
Вероятно, оба варианта равноправны, но так как они жаргонные и разговорные, то нет никаких правил их произношения и написания.
Но всё равно в споре, "стирка" или "стёрка", я за "стирку", хотя сам чаще говорю "ластик".

Comment: Но ведь "стерка", вполне возможно, произошло от "стереть" (стёр)

Comment: Хм, возможно. Я об этом не подумал.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то, правильно будет "стирательная резинка" или просто "резинка". А все эти "стерки" и "ластики" — школьный сленг, типа "домашки" и "физ-ры".
Кстати, "ластик" говорили, скорее, в  Москве. У нас в школе этого слова вообще не знали.

Comment: Ясно, что сленг. Но и у сленга есть орфография! Например, "велик" или "велек"? (в смысле велосипед). Я придерживаюсь первого написания, хотя и не задумывалась, почему.